# How to change background color of specific md-tab based on label in angular 1

Tags: css, angularjs

How to change the background color of specific md-tab based on the label in angular 1.
I have tried `.md-tab:first-child {background: green; }` this works based on id ,I have to give background color of tab based on the label and it's Id is not constant.

> UPDATE

code

```
<md-tab  id="tab1" label="Followup" ui-sref="app.ccc-patientDetails.followup">
            <div  ui-view="followup"></div>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab id="tab2" label="Symptoms" ui-sref="app.ccc-patientDetails.symptoms">
            <div ui-view="symptoms"></div>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab id="tab3"  label="Survey" ui-sref="app.ccc-patientDetails.survey" ng-if="ctrl.model.showSurvey">
            <div class="tabcolor" ui-view="survey"></div>
        </md-tab>


css
.md-tab:first-child {background: green; }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code what you tried?

Comment: I have updated the code please check.

Comment: looks like this is an outstanding angular-material issue, but one user came up with a directive to work around it: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3028#issuecomment-317961546

Comment: @mzulch  Can you please tell me how the above link would solve my issue?

Comment: Is this html something you can change? Can you add a class to those md-tabs?

Comment: out of the box, a class attribute on the original md-tab element is lost by the time you get to the final dom structure, but that link has a user-created directive to make sure those attributes are added to the actual md-tab-item dom element